# GVIM: auto scroll of a global command

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Let me start with the scenario: I am using GVIM on windows-

1. I do have a huge file say 3 GB size.
2. Search something using global command which has lot of occurrence in the file.
3. I have redirected this output of global command to a new file.

Problem: I need to scroll the out put pressing spacebar or other keys to get this output to a new file.

Is there anyway I may skip scrolling without loosing results?

Comment: use the command line, e.g. grep foobar bigfile > newfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, filtering is done more easily outside of Vim with tools like `grep`, but if you must...

- If you use `:redir`, you can use `:silent global/...` to suppress the output within GVIM. It will still be captured by `:redir`.
- If you basically use `:g/<pattern>/p` to filter matching lines, you could alternatively use `:vglobal/<pattern>/d` to *delete* non-matching lines, then persist what remains via `:w another-filename`.

Answer (score 3):

Use Vim's `:grep` command (`:vimgrep` would work, too) to search for `foo` in the file associated with the current buffer:

```
:grep foo %
```

Then, display all matches in the quickfix window:

```
:cwindow
```

In one go:

```
:gr foo %|cw
```

Reference:

```
:help :grep
:help :vimgrep
:help quickfix
:help :cwindow
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you I am using GVIM on windows. and not able to use command line. Using following command to get the output into new file but it force me to scroll all the way down to create a new temp file in split screen- 
nnoremap <silent> <F3> :redir @a<CR>:g//<CR>:redir END<CR>:new<CR>:put! a<CR>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `:!grep 'foo' path/to/file > newOutputFile.txt && vim newOutputFile.txt` It's probably not as clean as romainl's answer above, but I am not particularly familiar with using `:cwindow` (will look into it now though), so I found creating a new file and opening with vim to be a little more convenient for me.

Also, depending on what you are doing, I am a fan of [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) for doing grep-like things.

Comment: I forgot to tell you I am using GVIM on windows. and not able to use command line. Using following command to get the output into new file but it force me to scroll all the way down to create a new temp file in split screen- 
nnoremap <silent> <F3> :redir @a<CR>:g//<CR>:redir END<CR>:new<CR>:put! a<CR>